# Can't play video through HDMI output

Tags: pi-2, ssh, hdmi

I'm having a problem with my Raspberry Pi 2. I'm trying to run a video in command-line(ssh)

```
vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/video.avi
```

But It only displays in my command-line and not on the HDMI port.
When I connect Raspbery Pi 2 to the TV with HDMI cable it just shows the command-line, but nothing appears.

And when I launch any command in ssh terminal It does not appear in my TV. How to solve it?

Comment: How can a video be displayed in a terminal? Are you really using that ASCII video sink?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I didn't install anything but VLC player. When I start it it runs in command-line 0 and 1 makes a video, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a display to be used. When you issue a command via SSH, Raspbian will try to execute it and return any output via SSH as well. To use the remote (from your perspective) screen connected via HDMI, type in `export DISPLAY=:0` first.